401 (Unauthorized) JUnit test
I have the following Spring Security 6 configuration:
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

    httpSecurity
            .authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2Configurer -> oauth2Configurer.jwt(jwtConfigurer -> jwtConfigurer.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwt -> {
                Map<String, Collection<String>> realmAccess = jwt.getClaim("realm_access");
                Collection<String> roles = realmAccess.get("roles");
                var grantedAuthorities = roles.stream()
                        .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return new JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, grantedAuthorities);
            })));
    httpSecurity.sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    httpSecurity.csrf(CsrfConfigurer::disable);

    // Disable anonymous
    httpSecurity.anonymous(AnonymousConfigurer::disable);

    return httpSecurity.build();
}

Public endpoint that should be used without authorization:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/uaa/")
public class ApikeyAuthController {

......
    @PostMapping(value = "/public", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> apiKey(@RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody)
    {
        .......
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}

JUnit Test:
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApikeyAuthController.class})
@WebMvcTest
public class ApikeyAuthControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private ApiKeyService service;

    @MockBean
    private TokenService tokenService;

    @MockBean
    private ApiKeyAuthValidator apiKeyAuthValidator;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void apiKeyTest() throws Exception
    {
        when(service.getSummary(any(), any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(List.of(SummaryDTO.builder()
                .date(LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.MAY, 1, 12, 13))
                .enabled(12)
                .disabled(5)
                .build())));

        MultiValueMap<String, String> requestBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        requestBody.add("key", "password");

        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post("/public")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
                        .content(requestBody.toString()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}

I get always http code 401 (Unauthorized).
Do you know how I can configure /public endpoint to accept requests for above endpoint without authorization?

In your test, you make a request to '/public' when it should be '/uaa/public'

There are several ways to choose to mock security functionality, for example using SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors from spring-security-test, or @WithMockUser like described e.g. in the docs here.
Personally I prefer to mock SecurityFilterChain bean:
@WebMvcTest(ApikeyAuthController.class)
@MockBean(SecurityFilterChain.class)
class ApikeyAuthControllerTest {

   @Autowired
   private MockMvc mockMvc;

   @MockBean
   private ServiceInController serviceInController;

   @Test
   void test() throws Exception {
      when(serviceInController.foo()).thenReturn(something);
       
      mockMvc.perform(post(/uaa/public)
                        .contentType(contentType)
                        .content(requestBody))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}

By the way:

Don't use @ContextConfiguration to designate the controller under test, set it in the @WebMvcTest annotation.
You don't need to initialize mockMvc except for the @Autowired annotation above it, so you can remove your @BeforeEach method.
You don't need @AutoConfigureMockMvc because @WebMvcTest contains it.


@PeterPenzov, actually I thought that the already given example must be sufficient, but I edited it with some data

i dont really understand why you are linking to documentation for spring security 4.x when the current version is 6.x and the docs are here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/setup.html

@Toerktumlare, the link was given as an example of what a person should focus on when searching, I think he is able to find the version he needs. And t would be better if you wrote more detailed answer with an example of what the test really can looks like, and not just threw a link to the smallest piece of documentation

I would like to configure the security to be disabled only for path /public/** any idea why it's not working?

You could import your real security config class that contains your SecurityFilterChain, because there you say permitAll for /public. Would it be a solution? Simple place @Import(YourSecConfig.class) above the test class and do not mock securityfilterchain bean of course

linking to old outdated documentation is not good, and to use your argument, in the documentation i linked there are several pages that the author can read to help himself. I much rather help someone to help themselves, than to write their code for them. I have nwo linked to the correct docs, and i suggest you update your link in your answer too. Have a nice day

In ApikeyAuthController, there is a class level @RequestMapping annotation with the path as /uaa/. Then there is a @PostMapping annotation on the apiKey method with the path as /public. So the complete path would be /uaa/public. And if that's the path for which you need auth disabled, you'd need a couple of minor changes:

Change .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll() in the SecurityFilterChain bean definition to .requestMatchers("/uaa/public/**").permitAll()
Change .post("/public") in the test to .post("/uaa/public")

